# hide/show text area with textEditor depends on dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectors

I use the NicEdit(www.nicedit.com) text-editor on my Text Area which is working and the below code to hide and show text area after selecting a value in the drop down it will show the text area but this is what i need help with;

1) i want the text area to show even before you select any value from the drop down.

2) i want the Text editor(NicEdit) to show on all the text area after selecting a value from the drop down to show the text area.

Js For Text-editor(Nicedit):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nicEdit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
        new nicEditor({maxHeight : 200}).panelInstance('area');
    });
</script>
```

Js to hide and show text area:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function showHide() 
        {
            if(document.getElementById("color_dropdown").selectedIndex == 1) 
            {
                document.getElementById("hidden1").style.display = ""; // This line makes the DIV visible
            } 
            else {            
                document.getElementById("hidden1").style.display = "none"; // This line hides the DIV
            }

            if(document.getElementById("color_dropdown").selectedIndex == 2) 
            {
                document.getElementById("hidden2").style.display = ""; // This line makes the DIV visible
            } 
            else {            
                document.getElementById("hidden2").style.display = "none"; // This line hides the DIV
            }

            if(document.getElementById("color_dropdown").selectedIndex == 3) 
            {
                document.getElementById("hidden3").style.display = ""; // This line makes the DIV visible
            } 
            else {            
                document.getElementById("hidden3").style.display = "none"; // This line hides the DIV
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Html drop down:

```
<select name="menu"  id="color_dropdown" onchange="showHide()"> 
<option>Select Meun</option>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>   

    <textarea id="hidden1" name="area" display:none;"   id="area">ggggggggggggggggg</textarea>
    <textarea id="hidden2" name="area"  display:none;" id="area">hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</textarea>
    <textarea id="hidden3" name="area"  display:none;"  id="area">yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small note, you have more have multiple id attributes per text area and the second id's have the same value, this should be a class. The "display:none;" in your textareas are not in style tags(style="display:none;"), also try linking/loading the javascript at the bottom of the html page just before the the last html tag(or last body tag).

I am not sure if this will fix your problem, but these  could be issues.